# Duda en mySQL con una clave primaria compuesta

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Tengo un problema a la hora de meter datos en una tabla con una clave primaria compuesta. La tabla se llama `Compras_Productos` y su clave primaria es `Codigo_producto, NIF, Fecha`.

El problema me surge cuando al meter los datos me aparece el error 1062: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que no debería contar como duplicada, porque es la suma de los tres campos.

Dejo capturas de la sentencia de `insert` y también de la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí está la captura de la tabla, caducidad tiene valor Null, eso ya está modificado. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código y el error debe ir como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el script completo de creación de la tabla con todo y llaves y constraints? Creo que tienes una llave única en esa columna además de la llave primaria.

Comment: Ejecuta un **`SHOW CREATE TABLE Compras_Productos;`**. Copia el resultado y pégalo **como texto** en la pregunta, de ese modo podremos ver la estructura completa de la tabla, sus restricciones, índices, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano He añadido la sentencia de creación de la tabla

Comment: Pero la tabla tiene más datos supongo y por eso salta el error de clave duplicada. Revisa los datos existentes.

Comment: @A.Cedano La tabla de Compras_Productos está vacía, por eso me extraña que no funcione.

Comment: No puedo reproducir el problema de la clave compuesta, ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98b363acc1a12db229b0157c7ba532f2). Por favor, incluya (en modo texto) la estructura y algunos datos de las tablas: `Producto` y `Proveedor`.

Comment: Por fin lo he solucionado, no se que sucedía, pero con borrar la tabla y volverla a crear me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias!!